# Unable to configure react router element properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to develope a UI screen in react which looks like the one shown below in fig 1, the UI component contains two links namely L1, and L2 on the clicks of which should bring out the actual component to be rendered as shown in fig 2 which is the actual desired output.

But the issue i'm facing is whenever i click on L2, i got something like as shown in fig 3 which is undesirable i.e., the desired component gets rendered below L2. I am unable to understand how actually i should arrange my react router code.

[image: Reference UI piture]

Layout.js

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Link to="/component">Com</Link> 
        <br/> <br/>
        <Route exact path = "/" component = {welcome} />
        <Route path = "/component" component = {Com} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

Welcome.js

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Link to="/component">Com</Link> 
        <Route path = "/component" component = {Com} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

Com.js

```
<div>
    This the actual component to be displayed on button clicks
</div>
```

NOTE:

1. If i click on link L1 (refer fig. 1), i am getting the desired result, the above mentioned issue lies with link L2. Please help me or give me appropriate suggestion which might solve my issue.
2. Welcome, Layout, Com needs to be different components i.e., they should not be merged into one.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```js
<Route exact path = "/component" component = {Com} />
<Route exact path = "/" component = {welcome} />
```

reversing the route will fix this

Comment: Thanks for attempt but this doesn't work. How you thought that this may solve the issue. What's the logic behind this ?

Comment: from you Welcome.js don't return full Router. If you want to create nested route then return only <Route /> from component not <Router><Route /></Router>